# Validate xml based element presence or some flag

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I need to write an common XSD for two XMLs which is having a difference of one element.

like

```
 `<person>`
      `<name>ABC</name>`
  `<address>dgjjgg</address>`
`</person>`
```

the other one

```
<person>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>ABCD</name>
  <address>afgh</address>
</person>
```

How to validate the above two XMLs with a single XSD.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you'd like the 'id' element to be optional

```
<xs:element name="id" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peter. With the solution you gave it will allow id element. But my situation is I cannot pass id for both the XMLs as the first one is to create and the second one is for update. For create, I should not allow the tag. If by mistake if some one gives this tag it should show error. For update, that is in second xml only it should allow.

Comment: Well I personally think that's not something that you should try to handle in the xsd. I don't know what you would like to use it for, but based on what I understand I'd allow the id element and deal with it when handling the creation request